# How do I specify -rpath in my makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Instead of using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I want to specify the library search path through the `-rpath` option in the makefile. How can I do that? Assume the search path is the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

- use LDFLAGS to specify options for `ld`
- create separate rules for compilation and linking, there you can parr `-rpath=/what/ever` to `ld` directly
- use `-Wl,ldoption` for `gcc` to propagate `ldoption` to linker. In your case:

  `gcc ... -Wl,rpath=/what/ever ...`

Note that LD_LIBRARY_PATH serves for the **dynamic** linker/loader (`ldd`) not for the linker that creates executables (`ld`).

Answer (score 1):

The `-rpath` flag needs to be passed to the linker. Prefix all flags with `-Wl` to have gcc pass them to ld, e.g.

```
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath -Wl,.
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
LDFLAGS += --rpath-link /home/hp/Desktop/staging_dir/target-mips_uClibc-0.9.30.1/root-brcmref/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
```

Example of make file:

```
all: test


%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

test: test1.o test2.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: But don't you normally specify a path rather than file in rpath?